# Make heroku read specific file insteade of node_modules

Tags: node.js, heroku, node-modules

I wonder is there any way to make Heroku to read specific file instead of node modules. I'v made scraper with puppeteer but there is an error, I have found why thet error is appearse and I'v changed file in puppeteer files(in node_modules) so it works on my machine, but how can i make this changes on heroku if i dont have access to node_modules on heroku. So i wonder is there any way to make heroku to read specific file instead of reading this file from node_modules? Thanks.

Comment: Modifying files in `node_modules/` is _never_ a good idea. If you absolutely must modify a dependency, fork it and depend on your fork.

Comment: well in this specific situation modify is the only way i have found to go around this error.

Comment: That directory is managed by Yarn or NPM. Let the tool manage it. Again, if you need to modify a library fork it and depend on your fork.

Comment: Ty i will try this.